# Undo stack remains empty in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to undo/redo in multi document interface. I have different entities. Each entity has its own class. I have used UndoGroup but when I unable to push them to undoStack dont know whats's wrong there. Can anyone help me to solve the issue.

cadgraphicscene.cpp

```
CadGraphicsView::CadGraphicsView()
{
    undoStack = new QUndoStack(this);
}

QUndoStack *CadGraphicsView::m_undoStack() const
{
    return undoStack;
}

void CadGraphicsView::showUndoStack()
{        
    undoView = 0;
    // shows the undoStack window
    if (undoView == 0)
    {
        undoView = new QUndoView(undoStack);
        undoView->setWindowTitle("Undo Stack");
    }

    undoView->show();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_undoGroup = new QUndoGroup(this);
    QAction *undoAction = m_undoGroup->createUndoAction(this);
    undoAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Undo);
    QAction *redoAction = m_undoGroup->createRedoAction(this);
    redoAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Redo);
    menuEdit->insertAction(menuEdit->actions().at(1), undoAction);
    menuEdit->insertAction(undoAction, redoAction);
    menuEdit->addAction(undoAction);
    menuEdit->addAction(redoAction);
    undoAction->setEnabled(true);
    redoAction->setEnabled(true);
}

void MainWindow::updateActions()
{
    CadGraphicsView *view = currentDocument();
    m_undoGroup->setActiveStack(view == 0 ? 0 : view->m_undoStack());
}

void MainWindow::addDocument(CadGraphicsView *view)
{
    m_undoGroup->addStack(view->m_undoStack());
    connect(view->m_undoStack(), SIGNAL(indexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(updateActions()));
    connect(view->m_undoStack(), SIGNAL(cleanChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(updateActions()));

     setCurrentDocument(view);
}

void MainWindow::setCurrentDocument(CadGraphicsView *view)
{
    mdiArea->currentSubWindow();
}

CadGraphicsView *MainWindow::currentDocument() const
{
    return qobject_cast<CadGraphicsView *>(mdiArea->parentWidget());
}
```

I am confused with why I am not able to push entities to undoStack. Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in these two functions (see the inline comments):

```
void MainWindow::setCurrentDocument(CadGraphicsView *view)
{
    // The view argument is not used at all. You do not set anything here.
    mdiArea->currentSubWindow();
}

CadGraphicsView *MainWindow::currentDocument() const
{
    // mdiArea->parentWidget() returns the MainWindow, so this function
    // always returns 0.
    return qobject_cast<CadGraphicsView *>(mdiArea->parentWidget());

    // You should write it as
    // return qobject_cast<CadGraphicsView *>(mdiArea->activeSubWindow()->widget());
}
```

Comment: When I change the currentDocument() in mainwindow I get the following error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QMdiSubWindow'
     return qobject_cast<CadGraphicsView *>(mdiArea->activeSubWindow()->widget());

Comment: @user4345796, add `#include <QMdiSubWindow>`.

Comment: After including my program got crashed. Please help me to solve this

Comment: @user4345796, sorry, but I cannot debug it for you. Hint: check that all pointers returned by this call chain `mdiArea->activeSubWindow()->widget()` are not null.

Comment: I did mdiArea.activeSubWindow but again it doesnot goes into stack